# Hibernate - Query doesn't return anything

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, hql

Hello everybody i am new to the hibernate. I have a  method that is purposed to get a single column.

```
@Override
public List<User> getUsersByEmail(String email) {
    session = sessionFact.openSession();
    Query query = session.getNamedQuery("User.findByEmail");
    query.setParameter("email", email);

    return query.list();
}
```

After that, the returned value is used by the controller that further returns JSON data. It is supposed to return a user data but returns nothing.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/customer/customer-id/{email}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<User> getUserId(@PathVariable String email) {
    return customerDaoImp.getUsersByEmail(email);
}
```

Entity Class
**User.java**

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_user", catalog = "lifestyle", schema = "")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM User u")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByUserId", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.userId = :userId")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByFullName", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.fullName = :fullName")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByAddress", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.address = :address")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByContact", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.contact = :contact")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByGender", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.gender = :gender")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByDob", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.dob = :dob")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByEmail", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.email = :email")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByPassword", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.password = :password")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByActive", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.active = :active")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByCreatedDate", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.createdDate = :createdDate")})
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Integer userId;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 256)
    @Column(name = "full_name")
    private String fullName;
    @Size(max = 256)
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
    @Size(max = 30)
    @Column(name = "contact")
    private String contact;
    @Size(max = 10)
    @Column(name = "gender")
    private String gender;
    @Column(name = "dob")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dob;
    // @Pattern(regexp="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", message="Invalid email")//if the field contains email address consider using this annotation to enforce field validation

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 256)
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 256)
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "active", insertable = false)
    private short active;
    @Column(name = "created_date", insertable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdDate;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(Integer userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public User(Integer userId, String fullName, String email, String password, short active) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.active = active;
    }
//getter and setter
```

> http://localhost:8080/LifeStyle/api/customer/customer-id/nishandhungana41@hotmail.com

This is the url i have entered to get a value

Comment: Can't you used post method instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that does not recognize `.`

Try change to this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/customer/customer-id/{email:.+}", method =  RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<User> getUserId(@PathVariable String email) {
```

Comment: Missing URI template variable &#39;email&#39; for method parameter of type String

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer. Can you tell me the purpose of adding `:.+` Now it returns me the data

Comment: please see [this](https://thecruskit.com/spring-pathvariable-and-truncation-after-dot-period)

Answer (score 3):

The email must be URL encoded

```
http://localhost:8080/LifeStyle/api/customer/customer-id/nishandhungana41%40hotmail.com
```

So the @ char to be recognized

Comment: it still doesn't return anything

Comment: Check what you really get in the controller.

Comment: @StanishlavL - If i manually pass the email it returns a set of data but doesn't from url

Comment: Again. Print the `@PathVariable String email` in the controller to see real value obtained

Comment: it printed as in the url